# Stack Overflow Error in LibGDX when using "this.create()" and "this.render()"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I was following an online tutorial to make a space shooter using LibGDX and IntelliJ IDEA. Everything was working fine until I added the "this.create()" and "this.render()" functions. When they were added it caused at stack overflow error and I have no idea how to go about fixing it.

```java
    package com.mygdx.spacegame;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

    public class MainGameClass extends Game {
        public static final float SPEED = 120;
        public SpriteBatch batch;
        Texture img;
        float x;
        float y;

        @Override
        public void create () {
            this.create();
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
            img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
        }

        @Override
        public void render () {
            this.render();
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.UP)){
                y += SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            }
            if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.DOWN)){
                y -= SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            }
            if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.RIGHT)){
                x += SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            }
            if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.LEFT)){
                x -= SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            }

            batch.begin();
            batch.draw(img, x, y);
            batch.end();
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose () {
            batch.dispose();
            img.dispose();
        }
    }
```

When I run the code without the functions, it runs perfectly fine and the image moves around the screen using the arrows keys. But when I add the two functions back in I get this error:

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:13>3)
>   Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     at com.mygdx.spacegame.MainGameClass.create(MainGameClass.java:20)
>     at com.mygdx.spacegame.MainGameClass.create(MainGameClass.java:20)
>     at com.mygdx.spacegame.MainGameClass.create(MainGameClass.java:20)
>     at com.mygdx.spacegame.MainGameClass.create(MainGameClass.java:20)
>     at com.mygdx.spacegame.MainGameClass.create(MainGameClass.java:20)
>     at com.mygdx.spacegame.MainGameClass.create(MainGameClass.java:20)
>     at com.mygdx.spacegame.MainGameClass.create(MainGameClass.java:20)
>     at com.mygdx.spacegame.MainGameClass.create(MainGameClass.java:20)
>     at com.mygdx.spacegame.MainGameClass.create(MainGameClass.java:20)

It's been a while since I've used Java and I'm completely new to LibGDX so I wouldn't even know where to start with this one and I can't find any relevant solutions online. Hopefully someone here might know what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create method call itself which will create endless calls to create.

It can't be done without any stopping flag. Just remove `this.create();`

```
public void create () {
            this.create();
```

Comment: Further on in his tutorials, he moves most of the code in to a separate class in a separate package to use as a main game screen. I assumed the create function was required once the code was placed in a separate class. I didn't realise what was happening, it seemed to work fine for him.

Comment: on your specific question did the answer helped?

Comment: Heres the tutorial I was following, where he places the 2 functions in to his code before moving it to a separate class. [Tutorial Link](https://youtu.be/Pjg4KzckbrU)

Comment: Well now I feel like a dummy, thanks for pointing that out. Would of never looked at the rest of the tutorial without fixing the error, which would of lead nowhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

Call parent overridden method using `super` keyword instead of `this`. `this` represent current object so you got recursive call and then at end `java.lang.StackOverflowError`

```
@Override
public void create () {
    super.create();           // not required here
    ...
 }

@Override
public void render () {
    super.render();         // this required to call Screen render() method.
    ....
}
```